# Upgrade Ubuntu Kernel auto/manual

Tags: kernel

I've upgraded my ubuntu server kernel to 5.12 manually because of the Intel UHD 750 driver. My question is, will "apt dist-upgrade" upgrade that kernel once the official/signed one is above 5.12, or as I've installed it manually, automatic upgrades are disabled now?

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
This is what I did:

I've downloaded from the ubuntu mainline web the following packages and I've installed them:

- linux-headers-5.12.4-051204_5.12.4-051204.202105140931_all.deb
- linux-headers-5.12.4-051204-generic_5.12.4-051204.202105140931_amd64.deb
- linux-image-unsigned-5.12.4-051204-generic_5.12.4-051204.202105140931_amd64.deb
- linux-modules-5.12.4-051204-generic_5.12.4-051204.202105140931_amd64.deb

The reason is: After Kernel 5.11, there is support for new Intel UHD 750 Integrated Graphic Cards. The oficial kernel has not support, but once the official kernel goes above 5.12, I want to keep upgrading the kernel in the "regular" way (dist-upgrade).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't mentioned any OS & release, however 5.12 is not an *official* or *supported*) Ubuntu kernel so we don't know how it is packaged, my guess is NO it won't auto-upgrade as you've taken over that responsibility yourself by installing it (a later package which was called what?  the package name plays a part..), but it'll depend on how you actually added the package (no details were provided, nor from where).

Comment: Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS.  v5.12 is official >> https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.12.4/

Comment: That isn't an official Ubuntu kernel, but a *testing* kernel made available for testing...   Official kernels are found in repositories (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) and not via PPAs

Comment: That PPA is for testing. Please report any bugs that you discover. Your PPA kernel will be superseded by future PPA kernels (not Repo-provided kernels), as the PPA will *always* be ahead of the repository.

Comment: If you downloaded the packages (`wget` or equivalent) then installed (`apt` or `dpkg`) then they won't update.. as you've provided the package & taken over the responsbility of updating them yourself.  If you added the PPA then they'll get updates as long as the kernel team are working on 5.12, but they'll stop when they move to the next kernel (ie. you'll need to adjust yourself as you added it taking over the responsibility).   HWE kernel for 20.04 is still currently 5.8, it'll upgrade next to 5.11, then to *currently unknown* but that's using default packages and not your changed system.

Answer (score 1):

***Will "apt dist-upgrade" upgrade that kernel once the official/signed one is above 5.12?***

Let's make two assumptions:

- Your kernel metapackage (`linux-image-generic`) is still installed
- Your 5.12 kernel, if provided by a deb package, does not match the normal Ubuntu kernel naming schema.

If these assumptions are true, then your 5.12 kernel is independent of any Ubuntu kernel metapackage. Apt will continue to download new (lower-version) kernels as directed by the kernel metapackage, and those will exist side-by-side with your 5.12 kernel.

Eventually, the kernel version on the Ubuntu-provided path will pass 5.12. Your existing 5.12 won't be replaced by Ubuntu-provided packages because the names don't match. You will have two 5.12 kernels side-by-side.

When the Ubuntu-provided kernel bumps again to (let's say, 5.14 for example), the Ubuntu-provided 5.12 will be automatically removed. Your manually-provided 5.12 must be manually removed.

---

If the kernel metapackage assumption is false, then the answer is simple: You won't get any more Ubuntu-provided kernels.

If the naming schema assumption is false, then you will get apt errors when the *real* Ubuntu 5.12 kernel package does not match your 5.12 kernel package.

Comment: As I'm a beginner, let me tell you what I did. I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS. I've downloaded from the ubuntu mainline web the following packages and I've installed them: linux-headers-5.12.4-051204_5.12.4-051204.202105140931_all.deb // linux-headers-5.12.4-051204-generic_5.12.4-051204.202105140931_amd64.deb // linux-image-unsigned-5.12.4-051204-generic_5.12.4-051204.202105140931_amd64.deb // linux-modules-5.12.4-051204-generic_5.12.4-051204.202105140931_amd64.deb

Comment: The reason why I did it, is because Intel igpu UHD 750 is not working with the current official kernel ...

Comment: Telling us what you did and why should be in your question (you can [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1338781/edit) it) -- it will help make better answers. You asked a fairly generic question, so you get a fairly generic answer.